# guice doesn't inject implementation when with annotation

Tags: java, dependency-injection, annotations, guice

I have this code:

```
@CostRequest private IRequestUrlRepository costRequestUrlRepository;
```

and

```
this.injector = Guice.createInjector(new MainModule());
        routingResponseShortRepository = injector.getInstance(IRoutingResponseShortRepository.class);
        costRequestUrlRepository = injector.getInstance(IRequestUrlRepository.class);
```

and this in my `mainModule.java`:

```
    bind(IRequestUrlRepository.class).annotatedWith(CostRequest.class).to(CostRequestUrlRepository.class);
    bind(IRequestUrlRepository.class).annotatedWith(RouteRequest.class).to(RoutingRequestUrlRepository.class);
```

but I get this run-time error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.inject.ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors:

1) No implementation for com.waze.routing.automation.interfaces.IRequestUrlRepository was bound.
  while locating com.waze.routing.automation.interfaces.IRequestUrlRepository

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1035)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:994)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1044)
    at com.waze.routing.automation.runners.parallel.costRequest.BlParallelGenerator.<init>(BlParallelGenerator.java:76)
    at com.waze.routing.automation.runners.parallel.costRequest.BlParallelGenerator.main(BlParallelGenerator.java:44)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:64132', transport: 'socket'
```

how can i fix this?

I cannot annotate the

```
 routingResponseShortRepository = injector.getInstance(@CostRequest IRoutingResponseShortRepository.class);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an instance of [com.google.inject.Key](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/Key.html) as a parameter for `injector.getInstance`.

```
injector.getInstance(Key.get(IRequestUrlRepository.class, CostRequest.class));
```

> When feasible, avoid using this method, in favor of having Guice inject your dependencies ahead of time. (see: https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/Key.html)

Better use `@Inject` if possible. See: https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Injections

Comment: why is the error thrown anyway? I have an annotation on the field.

Comment: `injector.getInstance(IRequestUrlRepository.class);` this line throws the exception, because "No implementation for com.waze.routing.automation.interfaces.IRequestUrlRepository was bound." The implementation is bound for IRequestUrlRepository.class with a specific (`bind(IRequestUrlRepository.class).annotatedWith(RouteRequest.class)`). And the annotation of the parameter is ignored by the guice api... see https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/Injector.html

Comment: thanks. is there any way to solve this more elegantly? with annotation? or your suggested way it the way to solve this?

Comment: I do not know any other way... the best way would be to prevent the use of `injector.getInstance`.

Comment: Thanks. what do you mean by that? not using guice rather manually?

Comment: No, You should inject the dependency with `@Inject` where they needed, and if this bean is not a guice bean, create a factory and make it to a guice bean.`@Inject @CostRequest IRoutingResponseShortRepository myrepo;` e.g. as an attribute in a guice bean should work, but I think you know that?! https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Injections, I updated my answer